# How to add game objects in GameObjects array from c# code?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have an array in my C# script

```
GameObjects[] gameObjects
```

and I have an object

```
GameObject myObject
```

I want to create a random number of elements in gameObjects array and add myObject to every element of the array (my object could be cube, sphere or anything) and then Instantiate it on screen. How can I do this?

I already have code below

```
public GameObject[] myObjects;

void Start()
{
    float x = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.x - Random.Range(100, 200);
    float y = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.y - Random.Range(50, 150);
    float z = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.z + 800;
    Instantiate(myObjects[0], new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

and it works perfectly but with this code, I may only add objects to the array from unity properties but I need to add elements from the code. I found nothing on the Internet about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Elements To An Array Using Array.Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715029/adding-elements-to-an-array-using-array-add)

Comment: I understand it's not your question, but there is no real reason to use an Array over a List<>. The performance gain is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) might suit your needs better.

If you have to use arrays, you can initialize the size of an array on the `Start()` method.

```
public GameObject[] myObjects;

const int maxSize = 20;
const int minSize = 1;

void Start()
{

    int arraySize = Random.Range(minSize, maxSize);
    myObjects = new GameObject[arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        // Be sure to change the positions of each object
        float x = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.x - Random.Range(100, 200);
        float y = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.y - Random.Range(50, 150);
        float z = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.z + 800;
        Instantiate(myObjects[i], new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code wasn't what I exactly need but thanks to you I understood what I was doing wrong